# Cross table query

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, ms-access, ms-office

I have a table with a foreign key assigned to a master table. Usually, in SSMS, I'd get data from the foreign key table like so:

```
SELECT * from COMDATE
WHERE COMDATE.FORNLINK = MASTER.LINK
```

Or something similar.
In MS Access, this doesn't work. In fact, Access asks me to provide a *value* for `MASTER.LINK`. Is there a way to do this? Also, why is it so different in T-SQL?

Comment: SSMS is a LOT more powerful than MS Access. MS Access SQL also has different SQL syntax than most other databases. Perhaps your question should be re-worded : "Why is it so different in MS Access?"

Comment: @OverMind I was under the impression that Access used T-SQL? I would use SSMS if I could, but I can't figure out how to connect to an MDE from it.

Comment: No, Access does **NOT** use `tSQL` and both use different syntax for many 'similar' functions. http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/what-are-the-main-differences-between-access-and-sql-server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `MASTER` table

```
SELECT COMDATE.* from COMDATE, MASTER
WHERE COMDATE.FORNLINK = MASTER.LINK
```

I'll encourage to use `INNER JOIN` instead

```
SELECT C.* FROM COMDATE C
  INNER JOIN MASTER M ON C.FORNLINK = M.LINK
```

Comment: I don't want to see any information from `MASTER`. Would this not bring me all the records from both tables where there is a matching `LINK` record? The only thing I want to see is the content from `COMDATE`.
Additionally, what's the purpose of `INNER JOIN`? and why bother with it?

Comment: You said `"Access asks me to provide a value for MASTER.LINK"` I just provide a way to provide this value in a `WHERE` clause as you show in  your code. It is not recommended to do this, is clear to use `INNER JOIN`. Your question is not clear. For this request: `"The only thing I want to see is the content from COMDATE. "` This: `SELECT * from COMDATE` is enough

Comment: @Wolfish Show some effort.  select COMDATE.*.  Both syntax are joins.

Comment: @Wolfish did you see my edition and previous comment? Do it now fulfill your request? Let me know, or re formulate your question

Comment: Beg pardon, I've been reading up on Access. Yes, that appears to work. Thankyou.

Comment: @Wolfish Glad to help. Could you formally accept the answer?